# Displaying data in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

How do i display all data in a UILabel?

I am currently using this :

```
    for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)
    {
        lastname = [obj valueForKey:@"lastname"];
        name = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];

        NSLog(@"Name:%@\n Last Name %@\n", [obj valueForKey:@"name"],[obj valueForKey:@"lastname"]);
    }

    self.displayLabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Guest : %@  %@" ,name, lastname];
}
```

In the console I get all my data but in UILabel (displayLabel2) I just get one name…i just don't get it…

Comment: thank you no, it's just names and last names of guests but i'll make it wider and have a try…thx

Comment: Personally, i try everything i can before i ask question.

Comment: Do you understand that you log all objects but only last object from array is displayed in `displayLabel2`?

Comment: thx i worked out that only the last one gets displayed…how to display all names and last names i.e. guests ?

Comment: Yes i know i am trying to work it out, thank you to Jack and Nicel also, will keep posted as i said am newbie and humbly thank all.

Comment: ok worked thanks to code by Jack, thanking him again, was searching a long time for seemed simple task, but this road is a long one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that your code reads, on each loop through the `obj` NSManagedObject, the `name` and `lastname` will be reset. So the label will only display the final loop's data.

try creating a string within the loop

```
NSMutableString *stringText = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)

{
    lastname = [obj valueForKey:@"lastname"];
    name = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"Name:%@\n Last Name %@\n", [obj valueForKey:@"name"],[obj valueForKey:@"lastname"]);
    stringText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", stringText, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Guest : %@  %@" ,name, lastname]];

}

self.displayLabel2.text = stringText;

}
```

Comment: Your code will generate compiler warning because you are assigning `NSString` object to `NSMutableString` object (stringText).

Comment: Why not actually make use of the mutable string and append to it instead of needlessly reassigning it?

Comment: That's true, you could use `[stringText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@", Guest : %@  %@" ,name, lastname]];`